# Is gcd(a, b) = gcd(a mod b, b)?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

It seems to be the case for every pair of positive integers where $a>b$ but I can't really think of a way to proof this.

Comment: This is actually used as a way to calculate $\gcd$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: for a natural number $d$:

$d | a$ and $d| b$ iff for every $k \in \mathbb{Z}$: $d | (a + kb)$ and $d | b$

Comment: Ok thanks! but I am a little confused now. I can show that a mod b and b are divisible by gcd(a,b) but how can I strike the arc over too gcd(a,b) = gcd(a mod b,b)

Comment: If $d=\text{gcd}(a,b)$ and $e=\text{gcd}(a \text{ mod } b,a)$, then the hint gives you $d \leq e$ and $e \leq d$.

Comment: @Levix By the hint, $\,a,b\,$ and $\,a\!+\!kb,b\,$ have the same set $\,S\,$ of *common* divisors $\,d,\,$ so they have the same *greatest* common divisor $(= \max S).\ $ Note that $\, a\ {\rm mod}\ b\ = a + kb\,$ for some $\,k\in\Bbb Z.\ $

Answer (score 1):

Notice that $\gcd(a,b)$ divides both $a$ and $b$

$\implies \gcd(a,b) | a\mod b$

$\implies \gcd(a,b)$ is a common divisor of both $b$ and $a\mod b $

next, if some other number $k$ divides both $b$ and $a\mod b$, then :
 $k|bq+a\mod b \implies  k|a \implies k \le \gcd(b, a\mod b)$
QED.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!!but I don't get why $k|bq+a\mod b \implies  k|a$. Could you please elaborate that step? :)

Comment: say $a \mod b =r$,  then we can write $  a+bl = r$ ; since $k|r$ and $k|b$, we get : $0\equiv a+bl  \equiv a+0 \equiv a \mod k$